# screen signing document not appear, and event=ttl_expired

Tags: java, api, docusignapi

Hi, I've tried to sign a document using DocuSign's Embedded Signing feature, but when I send a request, the screen signing document doesn't appear, and it redirects me to a page with a URL parameter of **event=ttl_expired**.

I know that the ttl (time-to-life) = 5 minutes for URL tokens, can someone please help me?

Comment: You may want to refine your question a bit. Its very hard to understand what you want to fix and what is wrong. You mention Java but don't show any code related to what is happening or supposed to happen.

Comment: I understand and have rephrased their question...

Answer (score 0):

URL Tokens are only valid for 5 minutes.  If you are being re-directed to a screen that has a URL parameter of **event=ttl_expired** then that means you are trying to access a signing workflow from an expired URL token.

When URL tokens expire you need to generate a new one.  Have you seen DocuSign's API Walkthroughs?  There's 9 common use-cases of DocuSign's REST API and one of them is for Embedded Signing.  Each walkthrough has code showing you how to accomplish that task in 6 different languages (PHP, JavaScript, Java, C#, Objective-C, Python).

See here for the walkhthroughs:
http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthroughs

For instance, since PHP is easy to run from the command line here is a fully working PHP program to generate a valid URL token for signing, taken from the **Embedded Signing API Walkthrough**.  Just enter your credentials and a valid template Id from your account and this will work for you:

```
<?php

// Input your info:
$integratorKey = '...';
$email = '...@....com';
$password = '...';
$name = "John Doe";

// copy the templateId of an existing template here
$templateId = "C9D9D181-CE57-.....................";

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (retrieves baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results
echo "accountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create an envelope with an Embedded recipient (uses the clientUserId property)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array("accountId" => $accountId, 
    "emailSubject" => "Hello World!",
    "emailBlurb" => "This comes from PHP",
    "templateId" => $templateId, 
    "templateRoles" => array(
        array( "email" => $email, "name" => $name, "roleName" => "Signer1", "clientUserId" => "1001" )),
    "status" => "sent");                                                                    

$data_string = json_encode($data);  
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results   
echo "Envelope created! Envelope ID: " . $envelopeId . "\n"; 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 3 - Get the Embedded Singing View 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array("returnUrl" => "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
    "authenticationMethod" => "None", "email" => $email, 
    "userName" => $name, clientUserId => "1001"
);                                                                    

$data_string = json_encode($data);    
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes/$envelopeId/views/recipient" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$url = $response["url"];

//--- display results
echo "Embedded URL is: \n\n" . $url . "\n\nNavigate to this URL to start the embedded signing view of the envelope\n"; 
?>
```